# Does this have undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

What is the output of the following code? Suppose that necessary headers have been included.

Does this lead to undefined behavior? When compiled with g++ and run, it prints "test".

```
class A {
public:
    void test()
    {
        printf("test\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *pa = NULL;
    pa->test();
}
```

Comment: `When compiled with g++ and run, it prints "test"` UB doesn't mean it always crash. Actually it may and will work on many platforms. But it's UB anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Any dereference of a NULL pointer is undefined behavior. Thus your example exhibits undefined behavior too.

Comment: I guess it works in the given environment because `test` does not access a data member of an instance...

Comment: That may be. But speculation as to why it works in said environment doesn't really help with production coding, because this example should never be used in actual code.

Comment: No, you are totally right. I was just wondering.

Comment: @Codor `does not access a data member` change `test()` to `virtual` and it will crash too.

Comment: @owacoder, well, as a matter of fact, knowing how particular UB exhibits itself on your target platform is **invaluable** tool. It just used in the opposite direction - 'my program crashed yesterday after upgrade in B::foo(), but didn't crash before' - analyze the change - see that foo() started accessing members when it didn't before - conclude it was called with the bad pointer - fix the issue.